# Can “PrivateKey+MagicValue” decode pre-encoded data without intermediate key?

Tags: public-key, protocol-design

Let's say I want to build a public repository of encrypted files.

- `EncA(FileA)`
- `EncB(FileB)`
- `EncC(FileC)`

And I have users with Public/Private key pairs.

- `PubX/PrivX`
- `PubY/PrivY`
- `PubZ/PrivZ`

Now I want to give individual users permanent access to individual files by handing them some special `MagicKey` that is only for them.
However, I don't want them to be able to share `FilaA` with third parties *except* by sharing `FileA` directly (or by also sharing their private key).

i.e.: `decrypt(PubX, MagicKey(PubX, EncAPars), EncA(FileA)) yields FileA`, but with no intermediate result that can directly decrypt `EncA(FileA)`.

A close solution I was thinking about is:

- `EncA` is AES
- `PubX/PrivX` is RSA

with

```
 EncA(FileA) = aesEncrypt(aesKeyA, FileA)
 MagicKey(PubX, aesKeyA) = rsaEncrypt(PubX, aesKeyA)
 decrypt(PrivX, MagicKey(PubX, aesKeyA), Enc(FileA)) = aesDecrypt(rsaDecrypt(PrivX, MagicKey(PubX, aesKeyA)), EncA(FileA))
```

***but this does not do what I want***, because `UserX` could just share the AES key with third parties who download `EncA(FileA)` from my repository and then decrypt directly.

Comment: One practical problem you're likely to face is that, even if there was a scheme that could do what you want, it would likely be a lot less efficient than the standard hybrid encryption solution that you've already rejected as unsuitable. All the *efficient* schemes I'm aware of for public-key encryption of bulk data use a symmetric cipher to do the actual data encryption, and thus suffer from the same issue that revealing the symmetric key will let anyone decrypt the data.

Comment: Did you have a look at [Proxy Re-encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_re-encryption)? IIRC these schemes require a key for the proxy to translate messages from one encryption to another (but I don't know whether this key can be (made) message-specific...)